# How to disable "Get started with JRebel" after start of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, jrebel

After starting the eclipse (Neon.2 (4.6.2)) a window pops up in the lower right corner titled "Get started with JRebel" causing optical noise. How can I suppress the pop up?

I tried to disable anything related to JRebel from the menu "Window > Preferences" which seems with no avail.

I expect that this window does no longer appear as I am not using JRebel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Get started with JRebel" popup should disappear after the user has activated JRebel and has made the first reload with it. So to get rid of the popups, the following steps must be completed:
Install -> Activate -> Configure projects -> Startup with agent -> Reload.

However, as you mentioned that you do not wish to use JRebel at all anymore, then the easiest solution would be to just uninstall the plugin.